# too few arguments to function ‘NF_HOOK’

Tags: centos7, iptables, geoip

I am installing xtables-addon to CentOS 7.
configure command completes, Errors comes while making (./make)

/root/xtables-addons-2.13/extensions/xt_TARPIT.c:295:3: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘NF_HOOK’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
   skb_dst(nskb)->dev, dst_output);

/root/xtables-addons-2.13/extensions/xt_TARPIT.c:295:3: warning: passing argument 6 of ‘NF_HOOK’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
   skb_dst(nskb)->dev, dst_output);

/root/xtables-addons-2.13/extensions/xt_TARPIT.c:295:3: error: too few arguments to function ‘NF_HOOK’
   skb_dst(nskb)->dev, dst_output);

Answer (score 2):

No problem, in the file `xt_TARPIT.c` change define

```
LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(4, 1, 0)
```

to

```
LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(3, 10, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks. It works for me. xtables-addons-2.15